# regex for windows filenames laravel 4.2

Tags: php, regex, laravel, laravel-4

I have this controller that updates the filename of a file. At first, I did not know about the certain validations when editing a filename. So I had an error when renaming it. So now what I do is to implement a regex in my validations.

**Here's how it looks like:**

```
$rules = array(
        'eFile' => 'required|min:2|max:200| regex: /^(?!\.)(?!com[0-9]$)(?!con$)(?!lpt[0-9]$)(?!nul$)(?!prn$)[^\|\*\?\\:<>/$"]*[^\.\|\*\?\\:<>/$"]+$/ | unique:nsa_fileuploads,filename,' . $id . ',fileid'
    );
```

**The regex pattern:**

```
regex: /^(?!\.)(?!com[0-9]$)(?!con$)(?!lpt[0-9]$)(?!nul$)(?!prn$)[^\|\*\?\\:<>/$"]*[^\.\|\*\?\\:<>/$"]+$/
```

but once executed, I get the following error:

> preg_match(): No ending delimiter '/' found

Any ideas on what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: It might be that your `/` are unescaped. try this: `/^(?!\.)(?!com[0-9]$)(?!con$)(?!lpt[0-9]$)(?!nul$)(?!prn$)[^\|\*\?\\:<>\/$"]*[^\.\|\*\?\\:<>\/$"]+$/`

Comment: hello @Ohgodwhy ! i tried it but i still got the `preg_match(): No ending delimiter '/' found` error

Comment: See [`~^(?!\.)(?!com[0-9]$)(?!con$)(?!lpt[0-9]$)(?!nul$)(?!prn$)[^|*?\\:<>/$"]*[^.|*?\\:<>/$"]+$~`](https://regex101.com/r/aB8hP7/3). Try changing the `/.../` to `~...~`

Comment: hi @WiktorStribiżew i also got the `preg_match(): No ending delimiter '`' found` i also tried the other characters `@ , % ` in the regex101 link you provided but same error :(

Comment: Try using an array: `'eFile' => ['required', 'min:2', 'max:200', 'regex:/^(?!\.)(?!com[0-9]$)(?!con$)(?!lpt[0-9]$)(?!nul$)(?!prn$)[^|*?\\:<>\/$"]*[^.|*?‌​\\:<>\/$"]+$/', 'unique:nsa_fileuploads,filename,' . $id . ',fileid' ]`

Answer (score 1):

You can use an array here as your pattern contains a pipe symbol. Even if it is not an alternation operator and is inside a character class, the pipe [requires using an array](http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/validation#rule-regex).

Use

```
'eFile' => [
  'required', 'min:2', 'max:200', 
  'regex:/^(?!\.)(?!com[0-9]$)(?!con$)(?!lpt[0-9]$)(?!nul$)(?!prn$)[^|*?\\:<>\/$"]*‌​[^.|*?‌​\\:<>\/$"]+$/', 
  'unique:nsa_fileuploads,filename,' . $id . ',fileid' 
]
```

As for the regex itself, note that you do not have to escape special characters other than `\` (and also `-` (that is not at the start/end of the char class) and `^` (if not at the start of the character class), and `]` (if not at the start of the character class)) and `/` (because it is a regex delimiter) inside the regex pattern.